# Error in running flutter project which no permission

Tags: android, android-studio, flutter, android-testing, android-install-apk

Launching lib/main.dart on Android SDK built for x86 in debug mode...

> [!] Gradle does not have execution permission.
>       You should change the ownership of the project directory to your user, or move the project to a directory with execute permissions.
>   Gradle task assembleDebug failed with exit code 1
>   Exited (sigterm)

Comment: I've been having this issue as well since last night... I have ownership of the project folder too. I ran `chmod -R myusername .` just to make sure. Also, it's only on one project i cloned from Github... Tensor's project, if that makes any difference

Comment: the command not working

Comment: Right. It doesn't fix the issue. That's what I was saying.

Comment: I have same issue while building flutter app in AppCenter

Answer (score 60):

I got the same error trying to execute `flutter run` on a mac. Apparently, in your flutter project, there is a file `android/gradlew` that is expected to be executable (and it wasn't). So in my case, I ran...

```
chmod a+rx android/gradlew
```

...afterwards the `flutter` command worked.

Comment: First attempt Working

Comment: Thank you! This was the real answered! I've read a lot about migrating to Android X but that's not neccessary if the error is related to gradle execution permission

Comment: Thanks. That worked for me too. In my case I moved the project from windows to mac so the file was not created as an executable on windows.

Comment: @Jaydeepchatrola I'm guessing most linux users know this, so for OSX...  https://www.google.com/search?q=how+to+use+terminal+commands+on+a+mac

Comment: Did not fix it, still the same issue

Answer (score 2):

*FOR FLUTTER*
I have tried mostly everything mentioned here and on my own. The solution, actually, it is a series of solutions and worked for me, I am mentioning them try as you wish.

1. Make sure no antivirus *firewall is blocking,
   gradle.bat, gradlew.bat,
   git,
   flutter,
   android studio
2. Get the latest Gradle and install it to lower privilege directory, not in Program Files or Program Files (X86); I did it in D drive.
   Don't forget to update the path in Environment Variables.
3. I also installed JAVA Runtime (JRE).
4. Install git as it is necessary for flutter.
5. You can Check-in windows command line after installing each (Git, Gradle and flutter doctor). if nothing seems to work Restart the pc after each.

---

6. You might try it first, Disable the Gradle plugin and re-enable and restart android studio.

After this when you will compile /run the app it will take a long time please bear with that(at least 15 min just to be sure).

---

I had the app directory with Read, Write & Modifying permissions still, it was giving that error-
*Error code 1 "gradle does not have execution permission. you should change the ownership of the project directory to your user, or move the project to a directory with execute permissions."*

so I think it is related to the connection with the plugin.

Hope it helped :-)

Comment: Also check java.exe in your firewall execptions

Answer (score 1):

Try to set the execution flag on your gradlew file:

```
chmod +x gradlew
```

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue (Arch Linux), for some reason permissions where wrong in the flutter path:

```
sudo chown -R $(whoami) /opt/flutter/packages/flutter_tools/
```

Answer (score -3):

```
chmod a+rx android/gradlew
```

This works but for windows you need to install "Git for Windows"

Comment: Yes, but you have to add environment variable path
("C:\Program Files\Git\usr\bin" default location)
And also restart the IDE you are using